# C and X11 problems with coloring text

Tags: c, terminal, emulation, x11

I'm encountering a problem with X11 coloring text. In my program i have a `redraw()` function which is called each time there is a change, inside it i set the background color and foreground color, but then (im trying to emulate a terminal) for example if i execute command "ls", (before i added simple ANSI parse) i got something like `[01;32mfilename`, which means that the filename should be displayed in green. I parse that ANSI code and call `XSetForeground` in that `parse_ANSI`function, but nothing happens. All text is still original color. Im assuming `redraw()`just immediately overrides it, but i dont know how to fix this. Even then, anyone knows how i can color just that word?

Here is full code : https://pastebin.com/CW0R7TFn

Here are snippets (which i think are relevant):

```
void x11_redraw(struct X11 *x11) {
    int x, y;
    char buf[1];
    bool inside_escape_sequence = false;
    char sequence[16];
    int sequence_index = 0;

    XSetForeground(x11->dpy, x11->termgc, x11->col_bg);
    XFillRectangle(x11->dpy, x11->termwin, x11->termgc, 0, 0, x11->w, x11->h);

    for (y = 0; y < x11->buf_h; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < x11->buf_w; x++) {
            buf[0] = x11->buf[y * x11->buf_w + x];

            if (!iscntrl(buf[0])) {
                if (inside_escape_sequence) {
                    if (buf[0] == 'm') {
                        sequence[sequence_index] = '\0';

                        // Handle specific ANSI escape sequences and set the foreground color accordingly
                        if (strcmp(sequence, "\x1B[0m") == 0) { // Reset color
                            XSetForeground(x11->dpy, x11->termgc, x11->col_fg);
                        }
                        else if (strcmp(sequence, "\x1B[31m") == 0) { // Red color
                            XSetForeground(x11->dpy, x11->termgc, 0xFF0000);
                        }
                        else if (strcmp(sequence, "\x1B[32m") == 0) { // Green color
                            XSetForeground(x11->dpy, x11->termgc, 0x00FF00);
                        }
                        // Add more conditionals for other ANSI escape sequences as needed

                        inside_escape_sequence = false;
                        sequence_index = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        sequence[sequence_index++] = buf[0];
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                if (buf[0] == '\x1B') { // Start of an ANSI escape sequence
                    inside_escape_sequence = true;
                    sequence_index = 0;
                    continue;
                }

                // Set the foreground color before drawing the character
                XSetForeground(x11->dpy, x11->termgc, x11->col_fg);

                XDrawString(x11->dpy, x11->termwin, x11->termgc,
                            x * x11->font_width,
                            y * x11->font_height + x11->xfont->ascent,
                            buf, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    if (x11->selection.active) {
        // Draw selection rectangle if active
        int start_x = x11->selection.start_x;
        int start_y = x11->selection.start_y;
        int end_x = x11->selection.end_x;
        int end_y = x11->selection.end_y;

        XSetForeground(x11->dpy, x11->termgc, x11->col_fg);
        XFillRectangle(x11->dpy, x11->termwin, x11->termgc,
                       start_x * x11->font_width,
                       start_y * x11->font_height,
                       (end_x - start_x + 1) * x11->font_width,
                       (end_y - start_y + 1) * x11->font_height);
    }

    // Draw cursor as a vertical line
    XSetForeground(x11->dpy, x11->termgc, x11->col_fg);
    if (x11->buf_x < x11->buf_w) {
        XDrawLine(x11->dpy, x11->termwin, x11->termgc,
                  x11->buf_x * x11->font_width,
                  x11->buf_y * x11->font_height,
                  x11->buf_x * x11->font_width,
                  (x11->buf_y + 1) * x11->font_height);
    }

    XSync(x11->dpy, False);
}
```

and

```
void handle_ansi_escape_sequence(char* sequence, struct X11 *x11) {
    // Check for specific ANSI escape sequences and take appropriate actions
    // Modify the state of the X11 structure (x11) accordingly
    // Use X11 functions to redraw the window if necessary

    // Example: Change foreground color
    if (strcmp(sequence, "\x1B[31m") == 0) { // Red color
        // Set foreground color to red
        // Modify x11->col_fg or any other relevant state
        x11->col_fg = 0xFF0000;
        XSetForeground(x11->dpy, x11->termgc, x11->col_fg);
        x11_redraw(x11); // Redraw the window to reflect the color change
    }
    else if (strcmp(sequence, "\x1B[32m") == 0) { // Green color
        // Set foreground color to green
        // Modify x11->col_fg or any other relevant state
        x11->col_fg = 0x00FF00;
        XSetForeground(x11->dpy, x11->termgc, x11->col_fg);
        x11_redraw(x11); // Redraw the window to reflect the color change
    }
    // Add more conditionals for other ANSI escape sequences as needed
}
```

Comment: You know that `strcmp()` expects that both strings are `'\0'`-terminated at the same position, right?

Comment: Why `char buf[1];` - seems pointless and confusing.

Comment: All the strings you compare against start with `"\x1B"` but you've already consumed the escape character, it is not part of the remaining sequence that you store in `sequence[]`.

Comment: Likewise, it seems you never store the `'m'` in `sequence[]`. So that should not be part of the strings you compare against. Add some debug prints and I'm sure it will all become clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've given enough code for anyone to give a definitive answer, and it's entirely unclear how your `handle_ansi_escape_sequence()` function is used, but I see the following problems in your `x11_redraw()` function.

```
char buf[1];
```

It's really confusing to make this a one-element array.

```c
if (buf[0] == '\x1B') { // Start of an ANSI escape sequence
    inside_escape_sequence = true;
    sequence_index = 0;
    continue;
}
```

This detects the start of an escape sequence, but *does not* store the escape character in your `sequence[]` array. Therefore, when checking which escape sequence you got, you should not have `"\x1B"` at the start of the string you compare against.

Likewise, you detect the end of the escape sequence with this:

```c
if (buf[0] == 'm') {
    sequence[sequence_index] = '\0';
```

Again, you do not store the `'m'` in the `sequence[]` array. So the strings you compare against should not include the `'m'` at the end of them.

Your logic is very convoluted, with many `if... else` branches, and a few `continue;` statements, which are basically glorified `goto`s.

A simple state machine might be easier to understand and reason about.

Maybe something like this (completely untested, but I hope it shows the intent):

```c
bool inside_escape_sequence = false;
char sequence[16];
int sequence_index = 0;

for (y = 0; y < x11->buf_h; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < x11->buf_w; x++) {

        char c = x11->buf[y * x11->buf_w + x];

        if (inside_escape_sequence == false)
        {
            if (c == '\x1B')
            {
                inside_escape_sequence = true;
                sequence_index = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // logic to draw a character, elided
            }
        }
        else // inside_escape_sequence == true
        {
            if (c == 'm')
            {
                sequence[sequence_index] = '\0';
                process_escape_sequence(sequence);
                inside_escape_sequence = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (sequence_index < sizeof sequence)
                {
                    sequence[sequence_index] = c;
                    ++ sequence_index;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle overflow
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your `process_escape_sequence()` function would check what the escape sequence was, but not including the leading escape or the trailing `'m'` (because you never stored those in the buffer):

```c
void process_escape_sequence(const char *seq)
{
    if (strcmp(seq, "[31") == 0) { // Red color
        XSetForeground(x11->dpy, x11->termgc, 0xFF0000);
    }
    // etc.
}
```